# What is this Apple fourteen-pin video connector called?

Tags: mac, vga, av-cable, adapter

I'm trying to identify an Apple issued video adapter. One end has 14 pins, 7 on the top and 7 on the bottom. The other end is standard VGA. What is the other end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some Wikipedia research, I found that it's a [mini-VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-VGA).

[image]

Comment: Consider adding links that you found, it can be useful to someone else.

Comment: Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-VGA.

Answer (score 1):

According to [AllPinouts](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Apple_Video_14_pin) it seems to be a video connector for an Apple PowerBook.